# Access values in two dimensional NSArray in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

For the following two-dimensional array, I'd like to search the names for say John and then be able to retrieve the name John Smith and the id for John.

```
NSArray *employees = @[@[@"John Smith",@"1"],@[@"Ken Robinson",@"2"],@[@"Albert Jones",@"3"],@[@"Richard Johnson",@"4"]];
```

I can create the array, using the above syntax.  How would I search it for John and retrieve John Smith, 2 and access the employee's id, 2, something like `employees[0][1]` where 0 is the index and 1 is the dimension for id.

This is how I would search the array in one dimension but I'm confused on syntax for searching with a 2-d array.

```
-(NSString *)findNameInArray:(NSString*) searchstring
NSArray* employees = @[@"John Smith"@"Ken Robinson",@"Albert Jones",@"Richard Johnson"];
for (long i=0;i<[employees count];i++) {
            name = employees[i];
            if ( [name localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:searchstring] == NSOrderedSame) {
                return name;
            }//close loop
return @"":
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have in the first place an array of array, and not an array of dictionary, something like that: `@[@{@"id": @"1", @"name": @"John Smith"}, @{@"id": @"2", @"name": @"Ken Robinson"}]`, or an array of custom Object "equivalent"? That'd be better design

Comment: In your for loop: `name = employees[i];` become: `NSArray *person = employees[i]; NSString *name = person[0]; if ([name localizedCase...){ return person }`

Comment: An array of arrays is a poor choice to structure your data. Have an array of classes where the class has properties for the name and number. It will make many things much simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there's a good reason to have an array of arrays.  If so, you can filter the outer array with a predicate that applies to the inner array...

```
// look for @"John" anywhere in the 1st element (case insensitive)
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF[0] CONTAINS[cd] %@", @"John"];
NSArray *matches = [employees filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
```

You can also find a match to the start of the string with `BEGINSWITH`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, NSPredicate is the best solution in this case.